# Prove that this set of functions is not a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

It was asked to prove that the set $X=\{f: f(x) = (f(x))^{2}\}$ it is not a subspace of continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

I took $f(x)=1, \forall x$, and $g(x)=1, \forall x$. So both $f,g$ satisfy the condition. But, $f(x)+g(x)=1+1=2 \neq [f(x)+g(x)]^2$. So X it is not closed for addition and then not a subspace.

Is there another non trivial solution for this? Thanks!

Comment: If $f$ is any non-zero function in $X$ then $2f \notin X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are just two continuous functions that are always their own squares: the functions that are constantly $0$ or $1$. So it's hard to imagine a counterexample other than the one you found.